# The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, linq, entity-framework

I have two table Subscription and PackageType. Subs has FK as PackageTypeId. Now when I am inserting a new record in Subscription table using EF 4.1 it is throwing an exception

The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint `"FK_Subscription_PaymentType"`. The conflict occurred in database "MyDatabaseName", table `"dbo.PaymentType"`, column `'Id'`.
The statement has been terminated.

Tables information are:

Subscription Table:

```
   Id  (PK)

   PaymentTypeId (FK)

   Period

   date
```

PaymentType:

```
   Id (PK)

   Name
```

And the Code is as given below:

```
    public void Proceed(SubscriptionSessionData data)
    {

        if (data != null)
        {
            PMSCatalogEntities entities = new PMSCatalogEntities();

                Subscription subs = new Subscription();
                subs.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
                subs.ApplicableFrom = data.ApplicableFrom;
                subs.TenantId = tenant.Id;

                subs.PackageId = data.PaymentType;
                subs.PaymentTypeId = data.PaymentType;

                entities.AddToSubscriptions(subs);
                entities.SaveChanges();

        }
  }
```

Any idea about this issue?

Comment: Please provide the code that does this inserting

Comment: How is PaymentType table related here, you need to add more information as of now it makes no sense

Comment: Ankur & V4Vendetta  I have added more info related to code and my tables.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you should dispose the context when you don't need it anymore e.g. `using (var entities = new PMSCatalogEntities()) { /* your code */ }`

Comment: I assume that data.PaymentType is an integer? Where is its value coming from? I'd double check in the debugger what value it contains, then query the underlying table and make sure that a row with that PK exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already tested this scenario and it works great:

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PMSCatalogEntities entities = new PMSCatalogEntities();

            Subscription subs = new Subscription();
            subs.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            subs.Date = DateTime.Now;
            subs.PaymentId = 1;

            entities.Subscriptions.Add(subs);
            entities.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    public class PMSCatalogEntities : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Subscription> Subscriptions { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Payment> Payments { get; set; }

    }

    public class Subscription
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        public Payment Payment { get; set; }

        public int PaymentId { get; set; }
    }

    public class Payment
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Type { get; set; }
    }
```

And on the DB

```
TABLE [dbo].[Payments](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Type] [nvarchar](max) NULL,

TABLE [dbo].[Subscriptions](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [PaymentId] [int] NOT NULL,
```

The only thing I have to be sure is that a Payment with Id 1 for this example is persisted on the Payments table, and it works like a charm!!

Answer (score 0):

I saw this recently when the relationship used the primary keys of the parent and child record together, instead of the primary key and foreign key. There was a clue on the diagram for this in that the cardinality was wrong (1->0.1 instead of 1 -> *)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the value that you are assigning to subs.PaymentTypeId (data.PaymentType) is a valid Id from an existing record on the PaymentType table?

Comment: Yes I have double checked in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert a bad reference table primary key value, which is not presented in the database.